# Swift erro - cannot invoke initializer for type int with an argument list of type ()?

Tags: swift

Estou fazendo um curso de swift 2 mais a versão que estou usando é a 3, então estou pesquisando os códigos quando tenho algum erro para fazer a correção, mais alguns eu não tenho encontrado.

Agradeço se alguém puder ajudar

erro: cannot invoke initializer for type int with an argument list of type ()

```html
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath  indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
 
 let timesTabel = Int(btnSliderValor.value = 20) //erro 
 cell.textLabel?.text = String(timesTabel = indexPath.row)
    return cell
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Após revisar o código, resolvi o problema:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath  indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")

    let timesTabel = Int(btnSliderValor.value * 20)
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(timesTabel * (indexPath.row + 1) )
    return cell

}
```